# Add all reputation changes to the overview

Tags: feature-request, reputation

There is a nice overview of reputation changes but it is definitely not complete - if you add up all changes you don't get the expected value. Adding deleted questions would probably be too complicated but bounties should definitely be possible and nice to have, it took me some time to notice that I can see them somewhere at all. There are also "special" reputation changes like 1 point for creating an account or 100 points on meta if your main account surpasses 200 points, seeing them there would be nice. And even then I am missing 50 points on my Stack Overflow account - no idea whether it is some special award that I am unaware of or something entirely different.

Comment: +1 This would be a nice feature. I recently got the 100 points on Stack because my account went over 200 rep. There was a pop up but it doesn't remain in the "history".

Answer (score 4):

If you want a complete list, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation. You can use this to recalculate your rep if the values differ too much.

Comment: I did look at it but there isn't much additional information there. There is still a "bonuses" entry apparently throwing together bounties and site-awarded bonuses. And it starts counting at one, not at zero - so the initial reputation point isn't listed. Not to mention that this really is a debugging function, not a real site feature - new users won't find it (I certainly didn't until I read about it on meta).