# How to see all today's rep changes, across all sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, stackexchange.com

Is there a way to see all one's reputation changes, across all sites, for the current day?

I've found the 'reputation' graph on 'Network Profiles', which is useful, but that only shows reputation up to the previous day, and only for accounts above 200 rep.

The sort of thing I had in mind was something like the existing 'comments', 'posts' etc in the 'activity' section of 'Network Profiles', so that it lists all the different reputation changes listed, combined together from all my accounts, e.g.

```
Today's changes in reputation
Site1 logo    +2     5 hours ago    edit    Title of some question
Site2 logo    +10    7 hours ago    upvote  Title of some other question
Site1 logo    +2     7 hours ago    edit    Title of another question
```

The reasons I suggested it for just the current day are:

- For the top users, the list would be huge
- Beyond the current day, the existing Reputation graph is more useful - for those above 200, anyway

I think this sort of info would be really satisfying for people who are in the early stages of asking and answering on multiple sites, and when reputation is coming in in dribs and drabs.

(I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96019/169815), but it appears to be about all historical reputation changes on a *single* site.)

Comment: I contemplated making this a feature-request, as I've looked long and hard for this facility... Please let me know if I should rephrase it as a feature-request. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a feature-req to me (there might be a script around here somewhere that would give you *some* of this, but I can't seem to track it down if so).

Comment: A script would be useful, but I wonder how often it would be spotted by the kind of less experienced users I was thinking of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Achievements popup in the new Top Bar, launched in December 2013, provides exactly this functionality.

For a description, see the blog post [A New Top Bar for Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/).

Here's a nice summary, from that blog, of the benefits:

> Previously, if you wanted to know your reputation on every site you were active on, you had to visit *every one of those sites*. This led to some of us, well, compulsively cycling through sites and refreshing to see if we’d gained any rep. Now, there’s one convenient place to check from whatever site you happen to be on.

Thank you to whoever made this happen!

Here's a screenshot, from the blog post, of what it looks like:

[image: screenshot showing Achievements popup]